QGIS - calculate area of intersecting features or features within Atlas_geometry
I have a layout controlled by atlas by parcel numbers. Within the parcel numbers are geometries from another layer "IAN". I would like to sum the areas of the geometries within the atlas_geometry while using the atlas function, but the values are incorrect. When I use the expression
aggregate( layer:='IAN', aggregate:='sum',  expression:="teilflaeche", filter:=within($geometry, @atlas_geometry), concatenator:=', ' )
the result of the calculated area is 0. If I change the filter to intersects instead of within, then the result is e.g. the sum of the parcel 77/4 and 162/2, instead of only 77/4 or all the polygons within.


To clarify, you want the area of the intersection of IAN polygons with the current atlas feature? E.g. with parcel 77/4 as atlas feature you want the m² of the red area?
